# Parse, Swift, Facebook login issue "Unrecognized Selector sent to Class"

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I am trying to implement a simple Facebook login with Parse, Swift, and iOS 8.

I have followed the Parse documentation (to the best of my ability) and am getting stuck on what seems to be the simplest aspect...logging in.

I have:

1. Created Parse account
2. Created Facebook developer account
3. Linked the two via Parse settings
4. Added the frameworks to my project
5. Added the initialization calls to my app delegate

Then added the following code to my viewdidload function:

```
var permissions = ["public_profile"]

PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
    (user, error) -> Void in
    if user == nil {
        NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
    } else if user.isNew {
        NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUp", sender: self
    } else {
        NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")
    }
})
```

I get the following error when I run my project:

```
[PFUser _logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1002def88
2014-11-03 11:56:41.006 TestApp[9288:3511774] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[PFUser _logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:]: unrecognized     selector sent to class 0x1002def88'
```

Any help would be appreciated on this one...I am at a loss.

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: Can you download the latest Parse.framework and ParseFacebookUtils.framework and try again?  It appears this is a mismatch.

Comment: Yes this seemed to work...although, I didn't download it again, I created another new project and reimported them.  I can't explain it, but it worked.  Possibly another bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what user and error are.

Like this:

```
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        // your stuff.
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my project.  I'm using CocoaPods and had Parse 1.4 and Facebook-IOS-SDK 3.19.  I updated my libraries to the latest (using pod update) and that seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that "signUp" is spelt correctly? I see this all the time. Might be worth checking your code

```
NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUp", sender: self
```